# C++ AMP: array_view and index behaving strangely (unexpected values stored)

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, c++-amp

I have written a small test function that does not behave the way I want it to.

Basically, it should read an array and write back its content (later on, when this works, it should do more, but for now even this fails).

Debugging into the GPU Code, I saw that first few iterations (somehow getting executed in parallel.. which probably makes sense for a GPU, but surprises me when I debug) are working fine.. but then, after 1-2 Debug-Continues (F5), some previously correctly set values are overwritten with 0s. I do no really understand.. by the time I am on the CPU again, many values are 0, even though they should not be 0 (basically, they should have original data, which is a simple test sequence).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <amp.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

using namespace concurrency;

void AMPChangeBrightnessContrastWrapper2(byte* a, int len, float brightness, float contrast)
    {
        array_view<unsigned int> dst(len/4, (unsigned int*)a);
        //dst.discard_data(); 
        parallel_for_each(dst.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp) 
        {
            // split into bytes (in floats)
            float temp1 = (dst[idx])  - (dst[idx] >> 8) * 256;
            // this completely fails! float temp1 = dst[idx] & 0xFF;
            float temp2 = (dst[idx] >> 8)  - (dst[idx] >> 16) * 256;
            float temp3 = (dst[idx] >> 16) - (dst[idx] >> 24) * 256;
            float temp4 = (dst[idx] >> 24);
            // convert back to int-array
            dst[idx] = (int)(temp1 + temp2 * 256 + temp3 * 65536 + temp4 * 16777216);

        });
        //dst.synchronize();
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int size = 30000;
    byte* a = new byte[size];

      // generate some unique test sequence.. first 99 numbers are just 0..98
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        a[i] = (byte)((i + i / 99) % 256);

    AMPChangeBrightnessContrastWrapper2(a, size, -10.0f, 1.1f);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        printf("%i, ", a[i]);
    char out[20];
    scanf_s("%s", out);
    return 0;
}
```

So simple (planned) steps:

- initialize array
- pass array to GPU (as unsigned int array)
- split each unsigned int into 4 bytes and store them in floats
- (do some calculations, omitted here for simpleness)
- concatenate bytes-stored-in-floats again into the original position
- (repeat)

In case you wonder.. that is supposed to be color values..

Result is:

- some values are as expected, most have different values though
- seems like especially byte 0 (of each unsigned int) will have a bad value
- I first tried to convert unsigned int->byte->float with & 0xFF but that seems to completely have failed

Output is (but should be just increasing numbers starting with 0):

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9, 10, 11, 16, 13, 14, 15, 0, 17, 18, 19, 32, 21, 22,
>    23, 32, 25, 26, 27, 32, 29, 30, 31, 0, 33, 34, 35, 64, 37, 38, 39, 64, 41, 42,
>   43, 64, 45, 46, 47, 64, 49,

Questions:

- why the problem with & 0xFF?
- why does byte 0 of each unsigned int get a strange value assigned?
- I suppose I cannot create an array_view of bytes, I have to use ints or floats?
- commenting out the .synchronize in the end did not change anything - how come?

Answer (score 4):

> •I suppose I cannot create an array_view of bytes, I have to use ints or floats?

You cannot create an array or array_view of byte. C++ AMP only supports a limited subset of C++ types. You could use texture rather than array view. For image processing this has several advantages not least the packing and unpacking is much faster because it's implemented by the GPU's hardware. See full example below.

> •commenting out the .synchronize in the end did not change anything - how come?

You don't need the `dst.synchronize()` because the `dst array_view` goes out of scope which causes an implicit synchronization of the data back into CPU memory. Incidentally you should not be calling `dst.discard_data()` at the start of the function because if you do this will mean that the data from `a` will not get copied to the GPU.

Here's an implementation using texture<>. Points to note:

- Using a texture of unit_4 allows you to get packing and unpacking of
  your data for "free".
- Using clamp() is better than if clauses, firstly it uses an intrinsic function that
  the hardware is optimized for. In general branching within kernels is bad because it stalls all
  the threads in a warp, even if they evaluated the condition to false.
- You need two textures because, unlike arrays, they do not support aliasing.
- I've removed some of the temp variables. Variables use register space, which is very limited on 
  the GPU. You should minimize your use of it to make sure that all your threads can be executing
  not waiting for register space to be available.
- Explicit casting with static_cast<> means less compiler warnings and in general is considered 
  to be good (modern) C++ style.

And the code...

```
void AMPChangeBrightnessContrastWrapper3(const byte* a, const int len, 
    const float brightness, const float contrast)
{
    const int pixel_len = len / 4;
    graphics::texture<graphics::uint_4, 1> inputTx(pixel_len, a, len, 8u);
    graphics::texture<graphics::uint_4, 1> outputTx(pixel_len, 8u);
    graphics::writeonly_texture_view<graphics::uint_4, 1> outputTxVw(outputTx);

    parallel_for_each( outputTxVw.extent, [=, &inputTx, &outputTx](index<1> idx) 
        restrict(amp) 
    { 
        const graphics::uint_4 v = inputTx[idx];

        float tmp = static_cast<float>(v.r);
        tmp = (tmp - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        tmp = direct3d::clamp(tmp, 0.0f, 255.0f);
        const unsigned int temp1_ = static_cast<unsigned int>(tmp);

        tmp = static_cast<float>(v.g);
        tmp = (tmp - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        tmp = direct3d::clamp(tmp, 0.0f, 255.0f);
        const unsigned int temp2_ = static_cast<unsigned int>(tmp);

        tmp = static_cast<float>(v.b);
        tmp = (tmp - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        tmp = direct3d::clamp(tmp, 0.0f, 255.0f);
        const unsigned int temp3_ = static_cast<unsigned int>(tmp);

        tmp = static_cast<float>(v.a);
        tmp = (tmp - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        tmp = direct3d::clamp(tmp, 0.0f, 255.0f);
        const unsigned int temp4_ = static_cast<unsigned int>(tmp);        

        outputTxVw.set(idx, graphics::uint_4(temp1_, temp2_, temp3_, temp4_));
    });
    copy(outputTx, (void*)a, len);
}
```

You can find a lot more C++ AMP samples in the [AMP Book](http://ampbook.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this in-depth answer! I have 24bit RGB values (destroying the 32bit alignment). In that particular example (scaling) it does not matter at all (bytes are just equivalent). Do you know whether with using uint_3 I could get a mapping of 3-byte-aligned values to .r .g .b in a more elaborate case where I really need to distinguish colors?

Comment: I think using int_3 would result in unaligned memory access as the data is stored in the texture in its original format and unpacked into  int when accessed on the GPU. I'll double check this with the product team.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. so, to answer my own questions after some more trial and error and error again:

- & 0xFF is working fine, so are >> and <<
- that was my problem of not generating correct values, especially, I did not consider the (very limited) precision of float, which is well below an int's precision (well, the mantisse)
- still don't know
- still don't know, but it works the same (result/speed) with and without the .synchronize

In case you stumble upon something similar or need it, here is the solution (as originally intended), changing brightness and contrast in an array of brightness values:

```
void AMPChangeBrightnessContrastWrapper
    (byte* a, int len, float brightness, float contrast)
{
    array_view<unsigned int> dst(len/4, (unsigned int*)a);
    parallel_for_each(dst.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp) 
    {
        float temp1 = dst[idx] & 0xFF;
        temp1 = (temp1 - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        if (temp1 < 0)
            temp1 = 0;
        if (temp1 > 255)
            temp1 = 255;

        float temp2 = (dst[idx] >> 8) & 0xFF;
        temp2 = (temp2 - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        if (temp2 < 0)
            temp2 = 0;
        if (temp2 > 255)
            temp2 = 255;

        float temp3 = (dst[idx] >> 16) & 0xFF;
        temp3 = (temp3 - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        if (temp3 < 0)
            temp3 = 0;
        if (temp3 > 255)
            temp3 = 255;

        float temp4 = (dst[idx] >> 24);
        temp4 = (temp4 - 128) * contrast + brightness + 128;
        if (temp4 < 0)
            temp4 = 0;
        if (temp4 > 255)
            temp4 = 255;

        unsigned int temp1_ = (unsigned int)temp1;
        unsigned int temp2_ = (unsigned int)temp2;
        unsigned int temp3_ = (unsigned int)temp3;
        unsigned int temp4_ = (unsigned int)temp4;
        unsigned int res = temp1_ + (temp2_ << 8) + (temp3_ << 16) + (temp4_ << 24);
        dst[idx] = res;
    });
    dst.synchronize();
}
```

Also, even though I (think I) do few calculations, this ran 2-4 times faster (release/debug) than on CPU with an Intel HD 4000.

Comment: You can replace the tests for min/max values with the clamp intrinsic. Not only will this make your code cleaner it will also probably improve perf as this is using an intrinsic function that the hardware is optimized for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb204824(v=vs.85).aspx